# Subspace of differentiable real-valued functions over an interval

Tags: linear-algebra

Q: Show that the set of differentiable real-valued functions on $\textit{f}$ on the interval [-4,4] such that $\textit{f'}(-1)$ = $3 \textit{f}(2)$ is a subspace on $\mathbb{R}^{(-4,4)}$

This question comes from the 3rd addition of Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right. There is no solutions manual, and I'm not sure how to even start to solve it.

How do I begin to answer this question?

Comment: Do you know what you need to prove, in general, to show that something is a subspace of a vector space?

Comment: Are you sure it is '$f^{-1}$' written there? It just makes no sense. Most probably it wants to be either $f(-1)$ or $f'(-1)$, I guess...

Comment: Yes your right, it was meant to be the derivative. I'm still not sure how to approach it. How am I supposed to prove for all real valued functions?